# Type 'AllImage' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'/ 'Encodable'

Tags: ios, swift

```
struct AllImage: Codable {
    let mediaReferenceID: String?
    let url: String?
    let title: String?
    let description: String?
    let icon: String?
    let tags: [TagInfo]?
    let footerSection: FooterSection?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case mediaReferenceID = "media_reference_id"
        case url, title, description, icon
        case ctaInfo = "cta_info"
        case footerSection = "footer_section"
    }
}
```

Here the `TagInfo` and `FooterSection` is Codable too with containing only string types.

Any solution to this problem?

Comment: remove `case ctaInfo = "cta_info"` and add `case tags` to your `CodingKeys`. Unless of course you wanted `case tags = "cta_info"`

Answer (score 1):

CodingKeys should reflect all properties of that type inherits Codable and cant have extra field. So you should also add tags and remove ctaInfo.

```swift
struct AllImage: Codable {
    let mediaReferenceID: String?
    let url: String?
    let title: String?
    let description: String?
    let icon: String?
    let tags: [TagInfo]?
    let footerSection: FooterSection?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case mediaReferenceID = "media_reference_id"
        case url, title, description, icon
        // Commented out this
        // case ctaInfo = "cta_info"
        // Add tags
        case tags = "tags"
        case footerSection = "footer_section"
    }
}


struct TagInfo : Codable {
    
}

struct FooterSection : Codable {
    
}
```